# How to make this code reusable in SQL Server 2016 (except Union all)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to snap data for past. Let's say today in employee table when I snap I can see 1000 employees count. But this was not the case yesterday. 2 new employees joined today hence I am getting count 1000. If I want snap for yesterday I should get 998 an so on for last 60 days.

I have tried UNION ALL. But this wont help for more number of days.

```
/* Create Table */

CREATE TABLE dbo.EMPTable (ID INT, H_Date DATE)

/* Load Data */
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (1,'2019-04-17')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (2,'2019-04-17')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (3,'2019-04-16')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (4,'2019-04-16')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (5,'2019-04-15')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (6,'2019-04-15')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (7,'2019-04-15')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (8,'2019-04-14')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (9,'2019-04-14')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (10,'2019-04-14')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (11,'2019-04-14')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (12,'2019-04-14')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (13,'2019-04-13')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (14,'2019-04-13')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (15,'2019-04-13')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (16,'2019-04-13')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (17,'2019-04-13')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (16,'2019-04-11')
INSERT INTO dbo.EMPTable VALUES (17,'2019-04-11')

--SELECT * FROM dbo.EMPTable

/* Long query */
SELECT 
CAST(GETDATE()-6 AS DATE) AS Snap_Date, 
COUNT(ID) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.EMPTable
WHERE H_Date >=CAST((GETDATE()-6) -3 AS DATE) AND H_Date <= CAST((GETDATE()-6)  AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CAST(GETDATE()-5 AS DATE) AS Snap_Date, 
COUNT(ID) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.EMPTable
WHERE H_Date >=CAST((GETDATE()-5)  -3 AS DATE) AND H_Date <= CAST((GETDATE()-5)  AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CAST(GETDATE()-4 AS DATE) AS Snap_Date, 
COUNT(ID) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.EMPTable
WHERE H_Date >=CAST((GETDATE()-4) -3 AS DATE) AND H_Date <= CAST((GETDATE()-4)  AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CAST(GETDATE()-3 AS DATE) AS Snap_Date, 
COUNT(ID) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.EMPTable
WHERE H_Date >=CAST((GETDATE()-3)  -3 AS DATE) AND H_Date <= CAST((GETDATE()-3)  AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CAST(GETDATE()-2 AS DATE) AS Snap_Date, 
COUNT(ID) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.EMPTable
WHERE H_Date >=CAST((GETDATE()-2)  -3 AS DATE) AND H_Date <= CAST((GETDATE()-2)  AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) AS Snap_Date, 
COUNT(ID) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.EMPTable
WHERE H_Date >=CAST((GETDATE()-1)  -3 AS DATE) AND H_Date <= CAST((GETDATE()-1)  AS DATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS Snap_Date, 
COUNT(ID) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.EMPTable
WHERE H_Date >=CAST((GETDATE())  -3 AS DATE)
--------------------------
Expected Result
--------------------------
Snap_Date   I_Count
2019-04-11  2
2019-04-12  2
2019-04-13  7
2019-04-14  12
2019-04-15  13
2019-04-16  15
2019-04-17  12
```

If you see now, I am taking snap for last 3 days from today. Coming to yesterday again last 3 days from yesterday and so on.
Also, we cannot take H_Date as Snap_Date because what if one of the date doesn't have employees hired. Say, on 2019-04-12 there were no employees Hired. Then that particular date would not be available when taking H_Date as Snap_Date.

My apologies. Based on the solutions I see, I was not clear on my behalf of the complete problem statement. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: `SELECT e1.h_date snap_date,COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) i_count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date as h_date FROM Calendar e1 WHERE e1.date >= CAST(GETDATE()-6 AS DATE) AND e1.date <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  ) e1 LEFT JOIN emptable e2 ON e2.h_date <= e1.h_date AND e2.h_date>= DATEADD(day, -3, e1.h_date) GROUP BY e1.h_date;` This code worked for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, to be honest I don't fully understand your post. But to get the expected result from the given example data you can join the records with earlier or equal `h_date` to the set of distinct `h_date`s then group by the date and take the count.

```
SELECT e1.h_date snap_date,
       coalesce(count(*), 0) i_count
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    e1.h_date
                    FROM emptable e1) e1
            INNER JOIN emptable e2
                       ON e2.h_date <= e1.h_date
       GROUP BY e1.h_date;
```

If you expect there are days where no one joined so you had a "gap" in the series of day, you can also use a recursive CTE to get the set of data. Then use a left join and count the `h_date`.

```
WITH
cte
AS
(
SELECT 0 n
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1 n
       FROM cte
       WHERE n + 1 <= 4
)
SELECT e1.h_date snap_date,
       count(e2.h_date) i_count
       FROM (SELECT convert(date, dateadd(day, -c.n, '2019-04-17')) h_date
                    FROM cte c) e1
            LEFT JOIN emptable e2
                      ON e2.h_date <= e1.h_date
       GROUP BY e1.h_date;
```

(Change the start date and the count of days to go back according to your needs.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=6b7c819ae5970f4663885a2c6992f5a4)

Comment: If you see now, I am taking snap for last 3 days from today. Coming to yesterday again last 3 days from yesterday and so on. Also, we cannot take H_Date as Snap_Date because what if one of the date doesn't have employees hired. Say, on 2019-04-12 there were no employees Hired. Then that particular date would not be available when taking H_Date as Snap_Date.

My apologies. Based on the solutions I see, I was not clear on my behalf of the complete problem statement. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: @PKernel: The second query in my answer already addresses the problem when there is data missing for some days.

Answer (score 6):

First create a calendar table with a big enough range of dates for future needs

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar (Date DATE PRIMARY KEY)

--2010-01-01 TO 2039-12-31 inclusive. Adjust as needed
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar
SELECT TOP (10957) DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID), '2009-12-31')
FROM sys.all_objects o1, sys.all_objects o2;
```

Then you can outer join onto that to get the missing dates as below

```
SELECT C.Date, 
       SUM(COUNT(E.ID))  OVER (ORDER BY C.Date ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS I_Count
FROM dbo.Calendar C
LEFT JOIN dbo.EMPTable E ON E.H_Date = C.Date
WHERE C.Date BETWEEN '2019-04-11' AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP  BY C.Date
```

The execution plan for this is pretty efficient. Example below (with index on `dbo.EMPTable(H_Date) INCLUDE(ID)`)

[image]

Comment: I would totally recommend the second one over the first one.

Comment: I would add a tally table so we show results for days when no new person was hired.

Comment: @LuisCazares - yes the second one has some performance advantages. It can use an input ordered by `H_Date` to do both the grouping and the running total without any additional need to add a distinctify-ing step and `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is more efficient than the default `RANGE` in 2012 too

Comment: @Piotr - No need to use the comments to tell us what you would do. There is an answer box. You can add an answer doing it. If that was a hint for me to do it then it won't be taken as I'm finished on SO for the day!

Comment: @MartinSmith My apologies. I was not clear on my problem statement. I did not consider all the possible scenarios. I have added that now.

Comment: Create a calendar table with all needed dates and left join onto that then use that joined result in the same way as my answer

Comment: @MartinSmith That is not the exact solution I am looking for. What the stated query does is, it captures all the data from today to 1st date. In this case for date 2019-04-17 desired output coming is19, which is incorrect. Correct output should give 12 as the answer. As number of emp's between 2019-04-17 to 2019-04-14 are 12 and not 19. I have added exact thing hat worked for me in comment.

Comment: `SELECT e1.h_date snap_date,COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) i_count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date as h_date FROM Calendar e1 WHERE e1.date >= CAST(GETDATE()-6 AS DATE) AND e1.date <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  ) e1 LEFT JOIN emptable e2 ON e2.h_date <= e1.h_date AND e2.h_date>= DATEADD(day, -3, e1.h_date) GROUP BY e1.h_date;`

Comment: @PKernel - That is not efficient. I missed that you added that requirement. Just change `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` to `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`